# Eclipse shows error when there are none

Tags: android, eclipse, git

My eclipse project suddenly shows the red cross(for error) , but when I expand the project, the red crosses are not visible anywhere.

I have tried building , cleaning, rebuilding, etc, and all that does not seem to work

There is another weird thing that is happening now. When I choose to build automatically, It shows 'building workspace' on an on(in an endless loop.

I am using eclipse Luna, on windows 7.

Is it possible that its a git problem ?

Under problems, I get the error: 
"The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\myproject\bin\myproject.jar'

Comment: `Refresh` or `Clear` Project

Comment: As mentioned, all that I have done

Comment: Recently, have u any change in values folder?

Comment: I have two projects. One is library project, and the other is tha main project. I have error in the library project. I have not changed the values folder in the library project recently

Comment: Change `Build Target Version` of `Library` from `Properties->Android`

Comment: Create a new workspace and copy all your project into that workspace

Comment: delete bin folder and clean ,uncheck build automatically and try

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned before- usually if you're working on multiple projects at the same time the compiler has to have one of them being the "focused" project. This can be messed up when you have multiple projects opened at the same time.

If you have honestly done "File -> Refresh" and "Project -> Clean" then i recommend closing each project- hover over each project file, right click, "close project" and then restart eclipse.

If this does not work then i would love to see the actual source code- mostly because if the compiler will not run then it may be a workspace placement issue your actual libraries.

Just let me know if this is helpful or not. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Some time I am facing this issues. In this case i follow below steps:

1. Open your work space folder
2. goto in your project folder
3. goto bil folder
4. delete classes folder
5. Refersh your project from eclipse (select your project and press F5)

its always help for me. I hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a gradle project, refresh your gradle project.

Right click on your project -> Gradle -> Refresh Gradle Project.

It worked for me.